# Making the toolbar blend into the title bar

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have some simple code for generating the toolbar and the result I get looks like:

[image]

where the toolbar and the titlebar are distinct. Is there a way to make the toolbar blend into the titlebar like:

[image]

Here's my code so far

```
def initToolbar(self):

  self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Options")

  # Makes the next toolbar appear underneath this one
  self.addToolBarBreak()

def initMenubar(self):

  menubar = self.menuBar()

  file = menubar.addMenu("File")
  edit = menubar.addMenu("Edit")
  view = menubar.addMenu("View")

def initUI(self):

    self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.text)

    self.initToolbar()
    self.initMenubar()

    ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe coloring the toolbar with the title bar's color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go [QMainWindow::setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(bool)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#unifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac-prop)